# как сделать проверку в SQLite

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Если в бд есть новость, вывести тост....если нету в бд - добавляю её.
как сравнивать?

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {


    if (isChecked) {
        this.insert(new News(
                contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle(),
                contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDescription(),
                contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl(),
                contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPublished(),
                contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUpdated(),
                contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getAuthor(),
                111,
                contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDescVisible()));

        Toast.makeText(context, "Добавлено в избранные", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

         //db.delete("news", id, null);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Удаленно из избранных", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: что конкретно вы хотите сравнивать?

Comment: данные в бд. Если есть запись в бд то записывать и вывести предупреждение, а если такой записи в бд нету то добавляю (как вот в коде)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все таки непонятно насколько идентична будет информация но например можно так:

```
 //добавление новой новости
public void addNews(String addNewNews) {
    //проверка наличия новости в БД
    // вытягиваем курсосром новости из БД
    cursor = db.query("news", new String[]
            {"news"},null, null, null, null, "news ASC");
    //пробегаем по курсору и ищем идентичную новость
     if (cursor!=null){
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
           availableNews = cursor.getString(0);
           if (availableNews.equalsIgnoreCase(addNewNews)){
               Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Новость существует",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               cursor.close();
               return;
           }
           else cursor.moveToNext();
       }
       insertNews(addNewNews);
    }        
}
```